# Bulgarian Solitaire

Tags: code-golf, game

[Bulgarian Solitaire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulgarian_solitaire) is a single-player game made popular by Martin Gardner in his [mathematical column in *Scientific American*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamagical_Themas).

You have `N` identical cards, split into piles. You take a card from each pile and form a new pile with the removed cards. You repeat this process until you reach a state you've already seen and so continuing would repeat the loop.

For example, say you have `8` cards, split into a pile of `5` and a pile of `3`. We write the pile sizes in descending order: `5 3`. Here's a transcript of the game:

```
5 3
4 2 2
3 3 1 1 
4 2 2
```

You first remove a card from each of the two piles, leaving piles of `4` and `2`, and a newly-created pile of `2`, giving `4 2 2`. In the next step, these decrease to `3 1 1` followed with a new pile of `3`. Finally, the last step empties the piles of size `1` and produces`4 2 2` which has already appeared, so we stop.

Note that the sum of the pile-sizes stays the same.

Your goal is to print such a transcript of the game from a given starting configuration. This is code golf, so fewest bytes wins.

**Input**

A list of positive numbers in descending order representing the initial pile sizes. Take input via STDIN or function input. You can use any list-like structure you want.

You don't get the total number of cards `N` as an input.

**Output**

Print the sequence of pile sizes the game of Bulgarian Solitaire goes through. Note that printing is required, not returning. Each step should be its own line.

Each line should have a sequence of positive numbers in descending order with no `0`'s. You may have separators and start and end tokens (for example, `[3, 3, 1, 1]`). The numbers might have multiple digits, so they should be separated somehow.

Print the pile-size splits you see until and including reaching a repeat. So, the first line should be the input, and the last line should be a repeat of a previous line. There shouldn't be any other repeats.

**Test cases**

```
>> [1]
1
1

>> [2]
2
1 1
2

>> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
7
6 1
5 2
4 2 1
3 3 1
3 2 2
3 2 1 1
4 2 1

>> [5, 3]
5 3
4 2 2
3 3 1 1
4 2 2

>> [3, 2, 1]
3 2 1
3 2 1

>> [4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
4 4 3 2 1
5 3 3 2 1
5 4 2 2 1
5 4 3 1 1
5 4 3 2
4 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>40</s> 25

```
QW!}QY~Y]Q=Q_S+fTmtdQ]lQQ
```

This is pretty close to a translation of my python 2 answer.

Sample run:

Input:

```
[4,4,3,2,1]
```

Output:

```
[4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[5, 3, 3, 2, 1]
[5, 4, 2, 2, 1]
[5, 4, 3, 1, 1]
[5, 4, 3, 2]
[4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

How it works:

```
Q                          Q = eval(input()) # automatic
 W!}QY                     while not Q in Y:
      ~Y]Q                     Y += [Q]
               fTmtdQ                     filter(lambda T: T, map(lambda d: d - 1, Q))
            _S+      ]lQ           sorted(                                             + [len(Q)])[::-1]
          =Q_S+fTmtdQ]lQ       Q = sorted(filter(lambda T: T, map(lambda d: d - 1, Q)) + [len(Q)])[::-1]
                        Q      print(Q)
QW!}QY~Y]Q=Q_S+fTmtdQ]lQQ
```

Comment: 1. You can replace `v$input()$` with `Q`. 2. If you store the list in decreasing order, you don't need `N` at all: `W!}QYQ~Y]Q=Q_S+fTmtdQ]lQ;Q`

Comment: @Dennis Thanks, I couldn't figure out how to do that; I knew there was a way to do so.

Comment: Here's what I did, totally independently: `QW!}QY~Y]Q=Q_S+]lQfTmtdQQ`. It's exactly the same, character for character, up to commutativity.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 98

```ruby
f=->c{g={c=>1}
p *loop{c=(c.map(&:pred)<<c.size).sort.reverse-[0]
g[c]?(break g.keys<<c): g[c]=1}}
```

### Explanation

- Input is taken as the arguments to a lambda. It expects an `Array`.
- Previous game states are stored in the `Hash` `g`.
- To create a new game state, use `Array#map` to decrease every element by 1, add the length of the `Array` as an element, sort it in decreasing order and delete the element `0`.
- To check if a game state has been seen before, checking if `g` has a key for new game state is sufficient.

Comment: +1 Really neat Ruby golfing here! However, while the `sort_by` thing is certainly clever, `sort.reverse` is actually one character shorter ^^

Comment: Aww, that's too bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 26 bytes

```
q{~_:(_,+0-$W%]___&=}g{p}/
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

#### Example run

```
$ cjam <(echo 'q{~_:(_,+0-$W%]___&=}g{p}/') <<< '[5 3]'
[5 3]
[4 2 2]
[3 3 1 1]
[4 2 2]
```

Comment: That's some CJam!

Comment: Come on!, I know you can make it shorter than Pyth one!

Comment: If `:p` worked, I could...

Comment: Stop whining! `:p`

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, <s>35 34</s> 33 bytes

(Damn, this power cut that I was not the first one to post in CJam)

```
l~{_p:(_,+{},$W%_`_S\#0<\S+:S;}g`
```

Input:

```
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

Output:

```
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
[7]
[6 1]
[5 2]
[4 2 1]
[3 3 1]
[3 2 2]
[3 2 1 1]
[4 2 1]
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>148</s> <s>130</s> 101

```python
l=input()
s=[]
print l
while l not in s:s+=l,;l=sorted([i-1for i in l if 1<i]+[len(l)])[::-1];print l
```

This simply goes remembers all previous iterations, and checks if the new one is in that list. Then, it prints it out.

Sample run:

Input:

```
[4,4,3,2,1]
```

Output:

```
[4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[5, 3, 3, 2, 1]
[5, 4, 2, 2, 1]
[5, 4, 3, 1, 1]
[5, 4, 3, 2]
[4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Edit: I reread the specs to golf, plus applied a lot of golfing.

Comment: You're allowed to just print the lists as lists.

Comment: @xnor Ooh thanks, completely missed that.

Comment: This won't work with [5,3]

Comment: This gives the wrong output for `[4,2,2]`. There's an easy fix though.

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript, <s>50</s> 46

```
~.p$[]{[1$]+\.{(.!";"*~}%\,+$.-1%p\.2$?)!}do];
```

Can almost certainly be golfed further. [Try it out here.](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJbNCA0IDMgMiAxXSIKfi5wJFtde1sxJF0rXC57KC4hIjsiKn59JVwsKyQuLTElcFwuMiQ%2FKSF9ZG9dOw%3D%3D)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 - 103

```
p=input()
m=[]
print p
while p not in m:m+=[p];p=sorted([x-1 for x in p if x>1]+[len(p)])[::-1];print p
```

Similar to Quincunx' answer, but replaces appends with addition, and removes the last two lines.

Sample output:

```
[4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[5, 3, 3, 2, 1]
[5, 4, 2, 2, 1]
[5, 4, 3, 1, 1]
[5, 4, 3, 2]
[4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Umm, similar? This is identical; you simply took the golfing steps that were completely obvious. When I came back to mine, I golfed it, and discovered that this is now a duplicate answer of mine (or vice versa, however you want to view it)

Comment: I discovered your answer only after posting mine.  I'm ok with considering them duplicates of each other.

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, <s>40</s> <s>36</s> 34 bytes

```
]l~{a+_W=_p:(_,+$W%{},1$1$a#0<}gp;
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/) Enter input as a CJam-style array, like `[5 3]`, into the STDIN field. Output format is similar, so square brackets and spaces as delimiters.

Even if I golf this down further (which is definitely possible), there's no way to beat Pyth with this. Maybe it's time to learn J. Explanation coming later.

Comment: Not sure J will help, I can't get my APL below 38

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 99

```
import Data.List
g l=until(nub>>=(/=))(\l->l++[reverse$sort$length(last l):[x-1|x<-last l,x>1]])[l]
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (E6) 113

Worst entry so far :(

```
F=l=>{
  for(k=[];console.log(l),!k[l];)
    k[l]=l=[...l.map(n=>(p+=n>1,n-1),p=1),l.length].sort((a,b)=>b-a).slice(0,p)
}
```

**Test** in FireFox/FireBug console

```
F([4,4,3,2,1])
```

*Output*

```
[4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[5, 3, 3, 2, 1]
[5, 4, 2, 2, 1]
[5, 4, 3, 1, 1]
[5, 4, 3, 2]
[4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3: 89 chars

```python
g=lambda l,s=[]:print(l)!=l in s or g(sorted([x-1for x in l if~-x]+[len(l)])[::-1],s+[l])
```

Much like the Python solutions already posted, but with recursive function calls rather than loops. The list `s` stores the splits already seen, and short-circuits out the recursion in case of a repeat.

The function `print()` (this is Python 3) just needs to be somehow called in each loop. The tricky thing is that a `lambda` only allows a single expression, so we can't do `print(l);...`. Also, it outputs `None`, which is hard to work with. I wind up putting `print(l)` on one side of an inequality; `==` doesn't work for some reason I don't understand.

An alternative approach of sticking it in a list uses equally many characters.

```python
g=lambda l,s=[]:l in s+[print(l)]or g(sorted([x-1for x in l if~-x]+[len(l)])[::-1],s+[l])
```

Using `print(*l)` would format the outputs like `4 2 2` rather than `[4,2,2]`.